# Can I connect a AsObservable easy to an Observer

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I have a LinQ Expression resulting in a `IEnumerable<string>` statements.

This I want to route to an Observer with a `ForEach()` via OnNext.

Now I see a hint about using Reactive Extensions instead of ForEach and the code looks like this.

```cs
statements.ToObservable().Subscribe(
s => this.statementObserver.OnNext(new Statement(replyTo, jobId, s)));

// foreach (var s in statements)
// {
//  this.statementObserver.OnNext(new Statement(replyTo, jobId, s));
// }
```

Is this correct or can I directly connect my statements to the statementObserver ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the methods you've suggested, but this might be the more idiomatic way to do it:

```
statements
    .ToObservable()
    .Select(s => new Statement(replyTo, jobId, s))
    .Subscribe(this.statementObserver);
```

Do be careful exposing observers like that though. One call to `.OnCompleted()` and you've killed your object. It's best to pass in the observable and let the class observe it how it likes.